# How can I stop a reverve propagation of a link with Jquery

Tags: jquery, events

How can I stop parent binds to be called?

Example:

```
<div id="test">
    <a href="#" id="link" onclick="alert('testing')">TEST</a>
</div>
```

```js
$('#test').on('click',function(){
   alert('I dont want it to fire it up!');        
})
```

I just want to fire the onclick in the #link and not the event on the #test if I click on the #link

thanks for your responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
 event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: the inline handler doesn't use jquery and thus this doesn't work in ie

Comment: stopPropagation is valid javascript in modern browsers regardless of jQuery.

Comment: @JeremyLawson I said ie, not modern browser though

Comment: For an IE compatible solution, consider using this in conjunction with window.event.cancelBubble = true;

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `return false` in your event handler will prevent propagation. Unfortunately, it will also prevent the default behavior of the link; e.g. in your case loading `<page url here>#`:

```
<a href="#" id="link" onclick="alert('testing'); return false;">TEST</a>
```

## Edit

The [jQuery.event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object contains an interesting property called `target` which, in case of a bubbled event, will contain the element that received the actual click. You can use it if it makes sense:

```
$('#test').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is("#link")) {
        alert('#link was clicked; comment out this alert to ignore it');
    }
    else {
        alert('you clicked me but you did not click #link');
    }
});
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/gFp2G/)

By the way, I am wondering if there is a reason for mixing inline and unobstructive event handlers?

Comment: Stop misusing `return false;` http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: @gdoron you have the exactly same answer... also it's a link with href of `#`, preventDefault is actually desired here

Comment: `e.target.id == 'link'` is much much better. +1

Answer (score 0):

[`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) prevents event propagation. You have to pass the event into the event handler to do this, though.

```
$('#test').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: @gdoron: Wait, what? Am I detecting a hint of sarcasm? :)

Comment: I just tease you... :) the best answer. `return false` should really be used only when it's needed.

Comment: The op wanted to prevent propagation to the `"#test"` though

Comment: @gdoron: knew it! Yes, I got hit with the "stop misusing return false" slug myself. Esailja, this does that...?

Comment: The op wanted `I just want to fire the onclick in the #link and not the event on the #test if I click on the #link` (which I commented earlier), so it doesn't warrant a score over 0

Comment: Ohh, actually you didn't answer his question. he wanted something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10516238/601179). @Esailija. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

stopPropagation() is a valid javascript function both in and out of jQuery. jQuery helps support IE, but you can also just use cancelBubble to support IE.

```
document.getElementById('link').onclick = function(e) {
  if (e && e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); else window.event.cancelBubble = true;
}
```